# Fire a python script at a specific time

Tags: python, git, cron

Im attempting to build a sort of job system in python. This consits of a front end web page that allows people to schedule jobs to be run at x time. The PHP then writes the job including it's run time to a database. I Then have a python cronjob running on my server that will check in every 30 mins to see if there is a new job. If there is, it will fire a schedule script to count down to the exact minute of the event/job before firing.

The script im using for the scheduler can be found at: https://github.com/dbader/schedule. It seems like a pretty nice script and i found it on another SO page. However - after installing via PIP, the module doesnt seem to be working?

Attempting to run a schedule script - the Python engine crashes on:
    schedule.today.at('14:38').do(job)
I simply need to run a one time scheduler that can be reused to schedule multiple jobs at the same time. There is a small chance these jobs might repeat same time next week, hence i like the schedule module.

This is my example code built from a few snippets found on the GIT:

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    # Do some work ...

    print("Hello World")
    return schedule.CancelJob

#schedule.every(10).seconds.do(job)
schedule.today.at('14:38').do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

If anyone else is having the same problem - or has an alternative idea on how to achieve this - please let me know!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the source code on the master branch, `schedule` does not expose an attribute called `today`. If you've seen an example that used such an attribute than the issue would seem to be that you are on a version of the library from which it has been removed.

Unfortunately, this library doesn't look like a good fit if your main requirement is the ability to schedule one off tasks.

**Edit**:

There is no `today` attribute so the snippet mentioned in the FAQ won't work directly but you should be able to salvage the basic idea of it:

```
def job_that_executes_once():
    # Do some work ...
    return schedule.CancelJob

schedule.every().day().at('14:38').do(job_that_executes_once)
```

**Edit 2**:

Possibly useful: an "only do this job once" decorator.

```
from functools import wraps

import schedule


def do_once(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        return schedule.CancelJob
    return wrapped

@do_once
def some_one_off_job():
    # Do some work
    # No need to return schedule.CancelJob
    print 5

@do_once
def some_other_one_off_job():
    # hooray, decorators!
    pass

schedule.every().day().at('14:38').do(some_one_off_job)
schedule.every().day().at('14:38').do(some_other_one_off_job)
```

Comment: check the bottom of the FAQ @ https://github.com/dbader/schedule/blob/master/FAQ.rst

Comment: Would you recommend anything else?

Comment: Updating my answer in lieu of the FAQ. There is no `today` attribute but it looks like you can still salvage the idea they lay out of cancelling the recurring job immediately after it does any work it needs it.

Comment: Thankyou very muchly Sir. Enjoy your upvote and correct answer